# How to add a span tag to template in the onepage checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, template, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

I need to add a span-Tag next to the radio-Buttons in the payment template of the checkout.
And my question is HOW DO I DO THAT?
I can't find any template that matchs. There are several templates for payment but no matter which template I change in the CORE there is no visible change in the frontend when I call setup:static-content:deploy to create the new templates.
I also cleared all caches.

Comment: Do you have any checkout extension installed?

Comment: No there is no extension.

Answer (score 0):

You may change\override one of payment templates (for example **Check\money order** template located in **Magento\OfflinePayments\view\frontend\web\template\payment\checkmo.html**)
and clear **pub\static\frontend** folder